# How do I successfully notify Airbrake of a deployment when using capistrano to deploy a Node.js project?

Tags: node.js, deployment, capistrano, airbrake

This is a bit of an oddball question.

Capistrano 2.14.2

I'm using capistrano to deploy a couple of Node.js projects, and this works fine (from within the same rvm and gemset Ruby installation). However, I'd like to have Airbrake be notified of these deployments.

Using the 'airbrake' Node.js module, and calling

```
airbrake.trackDeployment({repo: '...'});
```

works, but not sure how to reliably call this just once at deploy time. If I call it within my server, then Airbrake is notified of a "deployment" every time my server starts, which is obviously not correct.

Adding

```
require 'airbrake/capistrano'
```

to deploy.rb definitely does not work.

How do others successfully use

```
airbrake.trackDeployment
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this solution http://dwradcliffe.com/2011/09/26/using-airbrake-with-node.html (which is clearly embedded in a Rails app.), I came up with the following, which depends solely on Javascript:

In my Node.js root directory, create a deploy.js file, like so:

```
var airbrake = require('airbrake').createClient("AIRBRAKE_API_KEY");

var deployment = {rev: process.argv[2],
                  repo: process.argv[3],
                  env: process.argv[4],
                  user: process.argv[5]};

airbrake.trackDeployment(deployment, function(err, params) {
  if (err) {throw err}
  console.log('Tracked deployment of %s to %s', params.rev, params.env);
})
```

In config/deploy.rb, add

```
require 'airbrake/capistrano'
```

and

```
namespace :airbrake do
  desc "Notify Airbrake of a new deploy."
  task :deploy do
    system "node deploy.js #{current_revision} #{repository} #{stage} #{user}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a simple js file you'd run locally (on your machine for example) that notifies airbrake as a last deploy task. You could for example use the backtick operator to run a task:

```
deploy.task :notify_airbrake do
    `node notify_airbrake.js`
end
```

If you don't have node installed locally, you could also pick one of the servers to run the notification script through ssh:

```
deploy.task :notify_airbrake do
    `ssh youserver "node notify_airbrake.js"`
end
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I figured I needed to do. If I did it locally, I'd have to pass in the correct deploy target environment to the .js program. If I used an SSH command, then I should be able to depend on the Node environment. Thanks! This was pretty straightforward. Enjoy my bounty :).